# Big O Notation asymptotic relationship

Tags: asymptotics

I cannot prove correctness/incorrectness of the implication of two functions f(n) and g(n) in Big-Oh/asymptotic notation

$$g(n) = \Omega(f(n)) ) \implies g(n) = O(n^2f(n))$$

I believe $g(n) = \Omega(f(n)) ) \implies f(n) = O(g(n))$

but not the other way around ?

Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 1):

You're starting with a function $g$ which is bounded below by a function $f$. If you multiply that function $f$ by $n^2$, do you think it will necessarily be larger than $g$ afterward?

What if $f$ is *much* smaller than $g$?

Comment: Is there a way that can be proved by contradiction ?

Comment: @HGOHGO Yes, try to come up with example functions $f$ and $g$. It's not really contradiction though, you want counterexamples.